# postgresql import data to database by columns

Tags: database, postgresql, csv

I am new to postgresql and I am trying to import my csv data into the database I created. I created a table in my database with a few columns. I would like to import my data to the table while filtering the columns to the ones I created in the database.

An example of my data source:

| X | Y | Z |
| --- | --- | --- |
| One | Two | Three |

For example, my columns in the table created: X and Z, so I would like only to import X and Z.
I hope I am being clear and sorry for any inconveniences.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a temporary table with all the columns from csv.

Then you can copy the file into the temporary table

```
copy temp_table (x, y, z) from 'csv_file_path'
```

After this you can insert into your table from the temporary table

```
insert into your_table (x, z) select x, z from temp_table
```

Comment: should I write this in public's script or my table's script ? thank you for the answer too!

Comment: what do mean by public's script or table's script?